# Best way to insert headers while writing file in java

Tags: java

I have scenario where i have to insert header manually which looks like below

Header:

```
<%@ package="test"
        imports="
      /* Many imports i know the list*/
        "
       %>
```

I have achieved this by string concatenation like sample below:

```
String header="<%@ jet package"+"="+"\"Testmodule\"" +"\n"+"imports"+"="+"\"java.io.File"+"\n"+
                "utils.ProjectUtils"+"\n"
                +"\""+" parallel="+"\"true\""+"%>"+"\n";
```

Note: I have more than 10 imports.This is just sample.

since the text is more and requires also proper alignment(like each import on next line and also escape "") when i am inserting header into other file, I want to know if there are any alternatives to do this in efficient way in java.

Comment: Why can't you just use `\n` for new line?

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the code that you have now, and describe the alignment requirements?

Comment: Try `System.getProperty("line.separator")`

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is a JSP Question

If it is, then use a static include (A static include is resolved at compile time)

```
<%@include file="includes/header.jsp" %>
```

or for for dynamic inclusion:

```
<jsp:include page="..." />
```

Comment: ,No its not JSP.I am just writing manually this header into some file. I have lot of string operations so just want to know if there is efficient way